# Python read / write on MFA enabled office 365 SharePoint list

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, multi-factor-authentication

I am getting errors while connecting to the SharePoint list. please find the errors below, which I received while trying different methods,

While using shareplum,
in get_security_token raise Exception('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', message[0].text)
Exception: ('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.')

from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth:
Response [403]

from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
ValueError: An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier '*.com}' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain.

I even tried Office REST API,
ValueError: An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.

Note: I don't have admin rights to get the client or secure IDs, and my Sharepoint is MFA enabled. So is there any alternate way to access SharePoint using python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.